# Primitive roots for primes (Burton's text book)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

On page 157 of Burton's elementary Number theory ,I am not sure if I understand the following reasoning:"Because 3 is a primitive root of 31 , any integer that is relatively prime to 31 is congruent modulo 31 to an integer of the form 3^k, where k is between 1 and 30 (with equality possible on 1 and 30)

Answer (score 1):

One standard definition of primitive root is that $g$ is a primitive root of the prime $p$ if $g$ has order $p-1$ modulo $p$. Thus $p-1$ is the smallest positive integer $j$  such that $g^j\equiv 1\pmod{p-1}$.

This definition immediately implies that if $g$ is a primitive root of $p$, then $g^1,g^2,g^3,\dots,g^{p-1}$ are pairwise incongruent modulo $p$. This implies that as $k$ ranges from $1$ to $p-1$, the remainder when $g^k$ is divided by $p$ ranges, in some order, over the numbers from $1$ to $p-1$.